# How do I get Milton to distinguish between child files and child folders?

Tags: java, milton

I have some code that retrieves a custom `DriveItem` class, where a `DriveItem` can represent either a file or a folder.

```java
@ChildrenOf // everything is a folder with the annotation, a file without
public List<DriveItem> getNextLevelDriveItems(DriveItem driveItem) {
    // ...
    return foldersAndFiles;
}
```

`DriveItem` has `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` methods that lets you know what kind of object the drive item is.  How can I get Milton to make use of this information?  Right now, all of my DriveItems show up as either folders or files, depending on whether or not I us the `@ChildrenOf` annotation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from Andriy Yevsyukov.  He suggested:

> You should extend DriveItem to differentiate folders and files - it
> could be just a marker classes

While it requires some refactoring of our code, the addition of two new classes enables folders and files to display differently:

```
public class MiltonFolder extends DriveItem implements FolderResource { ... }

public class MiltonFile extends DriveItem implements FileResource { ... }
```

Then we can have a method annotated with `@ChildrenOf` that handles the `MiltonFolder` but not the `MiltonFile`:

```
@ChildrenOf
public List<DriveItem> getNextLevelDriveItems(MiltonFolder driveItem) { ...}
```